# Wine does almost nothing when starting a game

Tags: wine, games

I am using Lutris with Wine Version: wine-ge-8-25-x86_64(default). If I press on "play" in Lutris it does nothing (instantly goes back to play without any error) and if I run wine then the executable I get following:

```
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
008c:fixme:wineusb:add_usb_device Interface 1 has 2 alternate settings; using the first one.
008c:fixme:wineusb:add_usb_device Interface 2 has 2 alternate settings; using the first one.
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:wineusb:query_id Unhandled ID query type 0x5.
0088:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0088:fixme:xinput:pdo_pnp IRP_MN_QUERY_ID type 5, not implemented!
0088:fixme:xinput:pdo_pnp IRP_MN_QUERY_ID type 5, not implemented!
0088:fixme:xinput:pdo_pnp IRP_MN_QUERY_ID type 5, not implemented!
0088:fixme:xinput:pdo_pnp IRP_MN_QUERY_ID type 5, not implemented!
002c:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00007FFFFE2FFEB0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 004278B0, 43) stub
0034:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00007FFFFE2FFEB0 0000000000000000): stub
0114:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 00006FFFF8BCB3F8, 43) stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (005BFEB4 00000000): stub
```

and after a few seconds: `003c:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (00007FFFFE2FFEB0 0000000000000000): stub`

And if you need the information: The game is Farming Simulator 17 from Giants Software. I already got other games running on wine with the same configuration.

Comment: Not every game works with Lutris or WINE.  Did you check the game against the WineHQ App DB to see if it actually *works* or not with WINE/lutris?